# What philosophical school does Raskolnikov belong to in Crime and Punishment?

Tags: ethics

At the beginning of the novel, Raskolnikov sees himself as a “superman,” a person who is extraordinary and thus above the moral rules that govern the rest of humanity. His estimation of himself compels him to separate himself from society.

His murder of the pawnbroker is, in part, a consequence of his belief that he is above the law and an attempt to establish the truth of his superiority.

Raskolnikov even rationalizes and justifies his actions to himself that he is doing service by claiming that a *louse* has been removed from society.

What school of thought does Raskolnikov belong to?

Comment: This sounds exactly like a homework assignment.

Comment: The psychopath school.

Comment: It is a fictional character and I think that the aim od the Author was not to "depict" a philosophical school. *Crime and Punishment* was published in 1866; we can see "traces of" the Russian [Nihilist](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Nihilism) movement : a Russian movement in the 1860s that rejected all authority. [Beyond Good and Evil: Prelude to a Philosophy of the Future](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Beyond_Good_and_Evil),  by Friedrich Nietzsche, was first published in 1886.